# How to create a query builder on object property in doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

It possible to create a query for columns type => object on doctrine 2?

Domain question in:

- Query Builder
- DQL

Example

```
/**
 *
 * Capacity Object Details
 * wgross = weight of item, wnet = neto weight
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="object")
 */
private $capacity;
```

When:

```
$capacity = array('wgross' => 19, 'wnet' => 9);
```

Possible query with pseudo where:

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT i FROM Entity\Item i WHERE i.capacity.wnet < 18');
```

Doctrine serialize the object type, i search on the web for possible solutions with:

- Doctrine Query Builder Expr
- Regular Expression

The type of columns on RDMS is longtext and not clob or blob, with value something like this.

```
O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:4:"wgross";s:0:"19";s:6:"wnet";s:0:"9";}
```

But nothing found.

Comment: Why not convert the `$capacity` field to Entity?

Comment: Because the object _$capacity_ may vary or change the attributes, is only for informational purposes and not relational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a possible solution but not the optimal one is to use a like expr:

```
 $qb->add($qb->expr()->like("i.capacity", $qb->expr()->literal("%text_to_search%")));
```

And after work in memory with Doctrine Criteria.